# Textview text with superscript

Tags: android, textview, superscript

This is strange. I have a text in my string file which has

```
<sup>\u00AE</sup>
```

in it. If I set this text to my TextView in xml file. It looks fine. But when I'm updating the it in the run time its not setting and displays like a normal letter.

.xml:

```
android:text="@string/you_dont_have_a_card"
android:id="@+id/txtNoCard"
```

.java

```
txtNoCard.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_card_is_not_activated)));
```

strings.xml:

```
<string name="you_dont_have_a_card">It appears you do not have a TestVisa<sup>\u00AE</sup> Debit Card on file.</string>
```

Comment: did you tri HTML.fromHTML ?

Comment: @njzk2 No.But when I set the text in xml its working fine

Comment: I even tried Html.fromHtml it didnt work

Comment: could it be something wrong with putting `<` inside an xml value ?

Comment: No. I dont think so because, If dont change the value which is already set in xml during runtime, Its displayed as superscript.

Comment: did you tried with something else instead of `\u00AE` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40662/discussion-between-rani-and-njzk2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XML, `<` and `>` are special characters. When including them, to avoid having the parser read them as enclosing tags, they have to be described as Entities.

In this case :

```
&lt;sup&gt;\u00AE&lt;/sup&gt;
```

The surprising thing in this case is the behavior of the TextView when the text is added directly as `android:text="@string/you_dont_have_a_card"`, which apparently uses a parser with a different behavior when facing special characters.